# Longtable and tabulary Together

Tags: tables, longtable, tabulary

Is it possible to have longtable and tabulary together in a table for autofit and Auto continuation of table in next page

Below is my code

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tabulary,capt-of,dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{showframe}


\makeatletter

\def\ltabulary{%
\def\endfirsthead{\\}%
\def\endhead{\\}%
\def\endfoot{\\}%
\def\endlastfoot{\\}%
\def\tabulary{%
  \def\TY@final{%
\def\endfirsthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}%
\def\endhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@head}%
\def\endfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@foot}%
\def\endlastfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}%
\longtable}%
  \let\endTY@final\endlongtable
  \TY@tabular}%
\dimen@\columnwidth
\advance\dimen@-\LTleft
\advance\dimen@-\LTright
\tabulary\dimen@}

\def\endltabulary{\endtabulary}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\captionof{table}{Sample Table 1 }\label{table_specrot}
\begin{ltabulary}{LLD..{1.3}}
x&y&1.1\\
x&y&1.244\\
x&y&1.3\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&y&1.2\\
x&yaaaa&1.2\\
\end{ltabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @David Carlisle, But that table doesn't have any Table Caption in it, how to enable Table Caption, all 3 table functions in a single Table, for example, decimal align using dcolumn, Autofit using tabulary and table continuation

Comment: you can use \captionof{table}{xxxx} from the caption (or capt-of) packages to do the caption before the table. dcolumn in tabulary should work with no problems.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry for bugging you :-), could you please add that caption in the above table coding and re post it to me, i am kind of having trouble compiling itabulary in this table

Comment: just put `\captionof{table}{Sample Table 1 }\label{table_specrot}` _before_  (not inside) the `\begin{ltabulary}`  (and use the capt-of package)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Thanks for that, the caption is working fine, but i can't see the table splitting to the next page, Please guide, Do I need to introduce any other things to see the table splitting automatically? you can see my updated code above

Comment: you have it in a `table` environment they never split see the linked question. Just remove the begin{table}   end{table}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for that :-), it's working fine, now one more issue, the caption should be displayed in the next page too with the Caption (Table 1 Continued)

Comment: no, you don't get that, sorry.